# CSS styles are not applying and JS files are not getting called from the server

Tags: asp.net

My application working fine on my development machine. I have hosted the same WINDOWS SERVER 2012 and i tested with in the server there also it is working fine.
But when i access it from out side server (through URL) some of my CSS styles are not applying and also i have implemented JQUERY code (with in myapp.js) in which i have functions which has $.ajax calls. Functions are gets calling but ajax call is not happening. I had reference to .JS files as shown below.

```
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please suggest me what might be the problem.

Comment: did you checked the browser console ? have you noticed any errors ?

Comment: Functions with in javascrit file are executing but $.ajax calls  within the function are not executing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a "../js in the start which denotes going to parent folder, and if i am not wrong you must have included this line in a layout file in the root folder. You need to check two things.

First is the JS folder containing inside the root folder, if not include it

Second if the JS folder is placed directly in the root folder, give fixed URL's instead of relative ones. i.e. use "/js/ instead of "../js/